# Parsing pipes from a line using expression

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have data that looks like this:

A|B|CC|DD|EE|FF|GG

Is there any way I can parse the string to output values of the pipe separators? Can someone give me some examples?

e.g.

A is the value before the first pipe

B is the value before the second pipe

etc.

etc.

Comment: is that just a string? should be trivial to just iterate over the string looking for `|`.

Comment: Marc, do you mind giving me an example?

Comment: no idea. never worked with informatica. just speaking in general. if you have string functions available, then start scanning through the string. start the beginning, scan for a `|`, and between those two points becomes your `A` value. then scan for another `|`. everything between the first `|` and the second `|` is your `B`, etc...etc...

Comment: Can you provide how your final result should look like?

Comment: Why not treat this as a pipe delimited file?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible within `Expression Transformation` but very inconvenient. You need to use `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` functions as indicated by @Vikas.

What you can also try is `Java Transformation` or...

A trick: how about dumping this (i.e. the string along with some key value) to a file prior to processing the dataset. And then use an additional `Source Qualifier` with `Column delimiter` set to "|" to do all the dirty work for you? Then you can join it all back together using a `Joiner Transformation` and the key value dumped to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSTR and SUBSTR combination or REG_ commands . Thanks !!